# How to classify image using IBM Visual Recognition API Version 3

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I have written below code in Node.js to create a classifier and then classify an image using **Visual Recognition API Version 3**, but the image isn't classified with the created classifier.

Same code has worked with earlier version. Please share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

```
var visual_recognition, params;
var ONE_HOUR = 3600000;
var CLASSIFIERID = [];


    // Create the service wrapper
  visual_recognition = watson.visual_recognition({
     version: 'v3',
     api_key: process.env.API_KEY || '<api-key>',
     version_date: '2015-05-19'
    });
```

**Creating classfier:**

```
params = {
    name: constants.DRIVERNAME, 
    driverOne_positive_examples: fs.createReadStream('./public/positive.zip'),
    negative_examples: fs.createReadStream('./public/negative.zip')
    };

    visual_recognition.createClassifier(params, function(err, classifier) { 
     if (err){          

        res.render('showError',{title:constants.TITLE1,
                                    err:'Something went wrong!'
                                    });
     }

     else{

        CLASSIFIERID.push(classifier.classifier_id);
         }  

    });
```

**Classify image:**

```
var parm = {
      images_file: img_classify,
      classifier_ids: CLASSIFIERID,
      threshold: 0.0
    };

visual_recognition.classify(parm, function(err, results) {
    var driverName,driverScore,driverId,driver;

    if (err){
      console.log('Error at classification!!!');

    }

    else{

        console.log('Image has been classified!!!');
    res.json(results); 
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Do you get any kind of logs?

Comment: Hi Joe,
It is not getting Error, but after Classifying the image the "results" JSON is having below data.
{"custom_classes":0,"images":[{"classifiers":[],"image":"test.jpg"}],"images_processed":1}.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `classifier_ids` using an array.

```
var parm = {
      images_file: img_classify,
      classifier_ids: [CLASSIFIERID], // <--- See this
      threshold: 0.0
    };

visual_recognition.classify(parm, function(err, results) {
    var driverName,driverScore,driverId,driver;

    if (err){
      console.log('Error at classification!!!');

    }

    else{

        console.log('Image has been classified!!!');
    res.json(results); 
}
```

[Visual Recognition Node SDK documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/node-sdk/master/VisualRecognitionV3.html#classify).